# vector subscript out of range C++ (substring)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, substring

So I'm having this problem with substrings and converting them into integers. This will probably be an easy-fix but I'm not managing to find the answer.

So I receive this string "12-12-2012" and i want to split it, convert into integers and call the modifications methods like this:

```
string d = (data.substr(0,data.find("-")));
setDia(atoi(d.c_str()));
```

But it gives me the error mentioned in the title when I try to comvert into an integer.

**EDIT:**
Turns out that the string doesn't actually contain a '-' but this is really confusing since the string in the parameter results from this : `to_char(s.diaInicio,'dd-mm-yyyy')`

More information: I used the debugger and it's making the split correctly since the value that atoi receives is 12 (the first split). But I don't know why the VS can't convert into an integer even though the string passed is "12".

Comment: No need for that first `c_str` call, and prefer something like `std::stoi` over `atoi`.

Comment: Yeah I edited now the first c_Str().

Comment: Are you sure that `data` does actually contain a `-`?

Comment: Yap, just checked with a cout.

Comment: Provide more code and more description of what you see in a debugger or via cout. Your "out of range" certainly means that some string is NOT what you think it is, but we can't guess what and why.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not save in the sense that it fails when `data` does not contain a `-`.

Try this:

```
std::size_t p = data.find("-");
if(p == std::string::npos) {
    // ERROR no - in string!
}
else {
    std::string d = data.substr(0,p);
    setDia(atoi(d.c_str()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please duplicate the problem with a very simple program.  If what you say is correct, then the following program should also fail (taken from Danvil's example, and without calling the unknown (to us) setDia() function):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string data = "12-12-2012";
   std::size_t p = data.find("-");
   if(p == std::string::npos) {
    // ERROR no - in string!
   }
   else {
       std::string d = data.substr(0,p);
       atoi(d.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: It runs smoothly. My question is how can the string from this: to_char(s.diaInicio,'dd-mm-yyyy') not contain '-' ?

Comment: So we have a different problem.  Maybe the "-" you claim to be looking at is not a hyphen (ASCII 45), but some other symbol that looks like a hyphen?

Comment: @user3127568 you said above that you checked the '-' with cout !?!

Comment: Apparently it is. But it's very odd since that line is implemented in Visual Studio and I typed it using an hyphen but it isn't a hyphen? That's strange.

Comment: Yes I printed on the console? What's the problem with it ?

Comment: Make sure that you're typing these characters using a bonafide text editor or copying these characters from a text editor (or in other words, you're not Using MS Word or something like that).  

I have seen cases where persons copy/paste from programs that fake out the hyphens (and double-quotes) with "fancier-looking" versions of these characters.  What winds up happening are problems similar to yours.

Comment: I even tried to replace '-' with '/', like this to_char(s.diaInicio,'dd/mm/yyyy') and it keeps blowing up one the conversion.

Comment: @user3127568 - Instead of printing out the characters, you should inspect the ASCII value of all of the characters in the string using the debugger or by other means.  Identifying characters "by sight" does not work all of the time -- maybe there are also stray non-printable characters within the string.

Or are you saying that atoi() is what is causing the issue?  If so, you should debug into the atoi() call and see what is being passed to it (again, use the debugger -- do not do this "by sight").

Comment: It's the atoi that is causing me problems.

Comment: @user3127568 - OK, so can you debug into atoi() to see where it goes wrong, or at least, inspect the parameter that is being passed?  I know that certain library functions in Visual C++ runtime will trigger a default error handler when that function is given one or more bogus parameters.

Comment: The value that is passed is "12" and nothing more since it only possesses these two characters. So why can't atoi convert it? It should work.

Comment: The last thing I will tell you is to debug into atoi() and see where it breaks down in your real program, and also create a simple program that just does atoi("12") and see what is different between a working program and your real program.